# Eclipse select text from under the cursor/caret and return it

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor

Working on an eclipse plugin, and doing some features for my editor, I have this method which selects highlighted text from the editor and returns it as a string:

```
public String getCurrentSelection() {
    IEditorPart part = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
            .getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
    if (part instanceof ITextEditor) {
        final ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor) part;
        ISelection sel = editor.getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
        if (sel instanceof TextSelection) {
            ITextSelection textSel = (ITextSelection) sel;
            return textSel.getText();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

But now I want that if I place my cursor inside a word it will select that whole word and return it as a string.

Besides a complicated algorithm where I parse the entire editor, get the cursor location, search for spaces left and right and whatnot, is there any easier way to get the text, where the cursor is placed, as a string?

Comment: If you have the sources for Eclipse, look for the implementation of the command which gets invoked via Ctrl+Alt+Left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get something working. For anyone facing the same problem, the following code works (for me, at least):

```
private String getTextFromCursor() {
    IEditorPart part = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
            .getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
    TextEditor editor = null;

    if (part instanceof TextEditor) {
        editor = (TextEditor) part;
    }

    if (editor == null) {
        return "";
    }

    StyledText text = (StyledText) editor.getAdapter(Control.class);

    int caretOffset = text.getCaretOffset();

    IDocumentProvider dp = editor.getDocumentProvider();
    IDocument doc = dp.getDocument(editor.getEditorInput());

    IRegion findWord = CWordFinder.findWord(doc, caretOffset);
    String text2 = "";
    if (findWord.getLength() != 0)
        text2 = text.getText(findWord.getOffset(), findWord.getOffset()
                + findWord.getLength() - 1);
    return text2;
}
```